# Error syncing pod,failed for registry.access.redhat.com (Kubernetes)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, redhat, docker-swarm

## kubectl create -f web.yml

## kubectl get pods -o wide

NAME      READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE       IP        NODE
httpd     0/1       ContainerCreating   0          1h            kube-node2

[root@kube-master pods]# kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME      READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE       IP        NODE
httpd     0/1       ContainerCreating   0          1h            kube-node2

> [root@kube-master pods]# kubectl describe pods httpd Name:        httpd
>   Namespace:    default Node:       kube-node2/10.10.0.102 Start Time:  Mon, 30
>   Oct 2017 17:47:38 +0600 Labels:       app=webserver Status:       Pending IP:
>   Controllers:   Containers:   httpd:
>       Container ID:
>       Image:            webserver
>       Image ID:
>       Port:         80/TCP
>       State:            Waiting
>         Reason:         ContainerCreating
>       Ready:            False
>       Restart Count:        0
>       Volume Mounts:        
>       Environment Variables:     Conditions:   Type       Status   Initialized    True    Ready   False    PodScheduled   True  No volumes.
>   QoS Class:    BestEffort Tolerations:  Events:
>   FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From            SubObjectPath   Type        Reason      Message
>   --------- --------    -----   ----            -------------   --------    ------      -------   1h        5m      16  {kubelet kube-node2}
>   Warning       FailedSync  Error syncing
>
> > pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "POD" with ErrImagePull:
> >     "image pull failed for
> >     registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7/pod-infrastructure:latest, this may
> >     be because there are no credentials on this request.  details: (open
> >     /etc/docker/certs.d/registry.access.redhat.com/redhat-ca.crt: no such
> >     file or directory)"
> >
> > 1h    8s  271 {kubelet kube-node2}        Warning FailedSync  Error syncing
> >     pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "POD" with
> >     ImagePullBackOff: "Back-off pulling image
> >     \
> >     "registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7/pod-infrastructure:latest\""

registry should go to hub.docker but here says

> Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "POD" with
>   ErrImagePull: "image pull failed for
>   registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7/pod-infrastructure:latest, this may
>   be because there are no credentials on this request.  details: (open
>   /etc/docker/certs.d/registry.access.redhat.com/redhat-ca.crt: no such
>   file or directory)"

Why ?

Please give me solution

Answer (score 3):

I encounter the same problem, and i found that i not install rhsm related software on machine, you can execute command "yum install *rhsm*" to solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. I could trace out the issue and solve it  installing rhsm package ( yum install *rhsm* )

Comment: The package name is not "rhsm", but "subscription-manager". You should issue the command:  "yum install subscription-manager", up voted nonetheless as this answer is useful.

Answer (score 0):

For me the file */etc/rhsm/ca/redhat-uep.pem* was missing.
I had to uninstall and reinstall docker/kubernetes on the minion to get the file back and it worked again. What a pain.

My environment is on CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708

And these rpms.

```
kubernetes-master-1.5.2-0.7.git269f928.el7.x86_64
kubernetes-1.5.2-0.7.git269f928.el7.x86_64
kubernetes-node-1.5.2-0.7.git269f928.el7.x86_64
kubernetes-client-1.5.2-0.7.git269f928.el7.x86_64
docker-1.12.6-71.git3e8e77d.el7.centos.1.x86_64
docker-client-1.12.6-71.git3e8e77d.el7.centos.1.x86_64
docker-common-1.12.6-71.git3e8e77d.el7.centos.1.x86_64
```

There ins no rhsm in CentOS.
[This post](https://serverfault.com/questions/506148/is-subscription-manager-available-for-centos) hast the alternative to rhsm for CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue on centos 7.

`yum install rhsm` is not working for me giving the following output:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: centos.ustc.edu.cn
* extras: mirrors.zju.edu.cn
* updates: centos.ustc.edu.cn
No package rhsm available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

**But** `yum install subscription-manager` works well for me.

Comment: can be installed using  'yum install -y * *rhsm**'. Use asterisk sign before and after rhsm . That would work fine.